# as3 - Removing EventListener where function has been defined in addEventListener parameters

Tags: actionscript-3, function, parameters, event-listener

If I add event listeners as shown:

```js
buttons[i][j].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(e:Event){trace("foo");});
```

How would I go about removing this EventListener?
I've tried this but, it doesn't seem to work. :S

```js
buttons[i][j].removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(e:Event){trace("foo");});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 myObject.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(event:Event):void
 {
      // event.currentTarget (in this case myObject)
      // event.type (in this case Event.ENTER_FRAME)
      // arguments.callee (reference to the current function)
      event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee);
      trace("foo");
 });
```

Comment: What would I use to remove the eventlistener?

Comment: JOKES I finally got it, thank you so much. I did see this solution in a previous questions, but didn't really understand how to use it!

Comment: I have added some comments to make it easier. Glad to help. If works, you can close this question.

Comment: hmm this seems to remove the eventlistener as soon as the function as executed, i was hoping to remove all the listeners via a function. :S

Answer (score 0):

It works when you define the function which is called on handling the event.
In your case:

```
buttons[i][j].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, myFunction);

function myFunction(e:Event){
     trace("foo");
}
```

And then to remove the EventListener:

```
buttons[i][j].removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, myFunction);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: oh sorry i should've been a bit clearer, I'm looking to pass parameters to the function in the eventlistener (if that'd even work)
so something like:
`buttons[i][j].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(){myfunc(i, j)});`
it's just that i don't seem to be able to remove it :S

Answer (score 0):

By definition you cannot remove that listener if you define it anonymously. That's the whole purpose of using that syntax. So if you don't mean that then you have to switch to a defined listener. If you do mean that then you have to use weakReference as:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(e:Event){trace("foo");}, false, 0, true);
```

The last parameter 'true' making it weak and making sure the event will be gc when the referenced object will cease to exist.

Using anonymous listener without weakRefernce set to true is an error.